# Function with an argument that can be different structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to get some complex feature which I will describe simplified here:

I have several kinds of structures with different variables inside:

```
struct param1 {
int varA;
int varB;
}p1;

struct param2 {
int varX;    
int varY;
int varZ;
}p2;
```

And on the other hand, I have a function that has to work with those structs, let's simplify they just print the data:

```
void function(int type_of_structure, <<struct param>>)
```

Then, the funcion should do something like this: Switching the type of structure, and printing the values accordingly.

```
switch(type_of_structure)
{
case 1:
printf("param.varA = %d \n",param.varA);
printf("param.varB = %d \n",param.varB);

case 2:
printf("param.varX = %d \n",param.varX);
printf("param.varY = %d \n",param.varY);
printf("param.varZ = %d \n",param.varZ);
}
```

I know this is possible to be done in C using functions with void ** arguments and casts. However,I am trying in many ways without succeeding.

How should I declare <> in the function in order to be able to distinguish the different types of structures?

Comment: Don't do that. Just don't. Don't try to enforce a concept that can be applied to a different programming language, that doesn't work well in [tag:c]. You can of course achieve similar behavior, but chaces are you will have a timed bomb of **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `union`, that's the real [c](/questions/tagged/c) way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum struct_type {
    STRUCT_TYPE_A, STRUCT_TYPE_B
};

struct A {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct B {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

union C {
    struct A a;
    struct B b;
};

void
print(enum struct_type type, union C object)
{
    switch (type) {
    case STRUCT_TYPE_A:
        fprintf(stdout, "(x, y) = %d, %d\n", object.a.x, object.a.y);
        break;
    case STRUCT_TYPE_B:
        fprintf(stdout, "(x, y, z) = %d, %d, %d\n", object.b.x, object.b.y, object.b.z);
        break;
    }
}


int
main(void)
{
    union C a = {.a = {1, 2}};
    union C b = {.b = {3, 4, 5}};

    print(STRUCT_TYPE_A, a);
    print(STRUCT_TYPE_B, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Using `void *` pointers for *generics* is terribly dangerous in [c](/questions/tagged/c). Also, [c](/questions/tagged/c) is not meant to have generic types, and dealing with that is difficult if you are used to think about generics, but it becomes clear that other solutions are more suitable when you understand that deeply.

**Note**: IMHO this code would be a lot cleaner having `int print_struct_A(FILE *target, const struct A *const object);` and calling them from within the `print()` function.

Comment: Adding to that, in C11 you can have anonymous structures. Then the members of the structures are treated as members of the union and you can write `object.x` instead of `object.a.x`.

Comment: Encapsulate it as `struct D { enum struct_type type; union C object };`  See [XWindows `XEvent` structure](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/structures.html) for a ubiquitous real-world example.

Comment: Although the other answers is what I initially was searching for, this method using unions is much cleaner and has more sense.

Actually I did not know about the existence of unions!

So I choose this as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Since you identify the struct based on the "tag" (`type_of_structure`), you can use `void *` and interpret it based on the tag:

```
void function(int type_of_structure, void *arg)
{
    switch(type_of_structure)
    {
    case 1: {
    struct param1 *s1 = arg;
    printf("param.varA = %d \n",s1->varA);
    printf("param.varB = %d \n",s1->varB);
    break;
    }

    case 2: {
    struct param2 *s2 = arg;
    printf("param.varX = %d \n",s2->varX);
    printf("param.varY = %d \n",s2->varY);
    printf("param.varZ = %d \n",s2->varZ);
    break;
    }
    }
}
```

And you'd call it:

```
function(type_of_structure, &param);
```

Comment: I was searching for this kind of answer. However, I find the method of unions much cleaner, and that is why I will chose that other answer instead.

However, your answer will be helpful for other tasks I also need to perform.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As possible, avoid obliging the user to call a function with the right enumerator and right matching type of object.

---

If one would like to venture into C11 `_Generic`, code could create a macro `DO_print(X)` that selects the correct print function.  `int type_of_structure` not needed.

Otherwise I recommend code simple call  the structure specific print function.

Given that the structures may be of arbitrary size, I recommend to pass them by their address.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct param1 {
  int varA;
  int varB;
} p1;

typedef struct param2 {
  int varX;
  int varY;
  int varZ;
} p2;

void DO_print_p1(const p1 *o1) {
  printf("param.varA = %d \n",o1->varA);
  printf("param.varB = %d \n",o1->varB);
}

void DO_print_p2(const p2 *o2) {
  printf("param.varX = %d \n",o2->varX);
  printf("param.varY = %d \n",o2->varY);
  printf("param.varZ = %d \n",o2->varZ);
}

#define DO_print(X) _Generic((X), \
  p1 *: DO_print_p1, \
  p2 *: DO_print_p2 \
  )(X)
```

Sample use

```
int main() {
  p1 o1 = { 1,2};
  p2 o2 = { 3, 4,5};
  DO_print(&o1);
  DO_print(&o2);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
param.varA = 1 
param.varB = 2 
param.varX = 3 
param.varY = 4 
param.varZ = 5
```

---

If code still wants to use a common `void function(int type_of_structure, <<struct param>>)` for perceived implementation ease, then hide it from direct user use/abuse through wrapper functions.

```
static void function(int type_of_structure, void *ptr) {
  switch (type_of_structure) {
    case 1: 
      const p1 *o1 = ptr;
      ...
      break;
    case 2: 
      const p2 *o2 = ptr;
      ...
      break;
  }
}

void DO_print_p1(const p1 *o1) {
  function(1, o1);
}

void DO_print_p1(const p2 *o2) {
  function(2, o2);
}
```